# Browser display shows old website. Unable to publish updated version via sites

Tags: google-sites

My domain is https://thehealingpotter.com. An outdated version of my website is currently live when you pull up my domain. I am attempting to change it to an updated version in/through sites, but when I publish, it does not update the site online (in the browser). I am hoping someone can help me figure out how to remove the old site and publish the new one.

On a side note: when I attempt to publish, it wants me to enter an address that has no .com.